# Apple Certification Process

Tags: iphone, certificate

I have made an app, now I want to send it to the App Store.
I want to run the app this on various devices, but have no idea how to do this.

I have made some apps in the past but they were never certified.

I know that certification is required, but I don't know if I should create a different certificate for that app or can I use same one?

Can anyone provide me information on this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can use the same certificate for multiple number of applications.

Once your certificate is in place, you will be required to create a provisioning profile of your application.

-Using this provisioning profile you can install your appilcation on iPhone.

-For development purpose you should create a developer Provisioning porfile.

-Once your application is tested and ready for sale on App Store you have to create a Distribution profile.

-Once done with this process you are required to install that provisioning profile on your device.

I recommend you should read the Apple documentation in your Agent account which you must have created as you have mentioned you already have a certificate.

They have explained in detail a full walk through for creating a certificate and Provisioning profile.

Hope this a cleared your initial doubts so that you can jump in for minute details.

Comment: Dude I am working right now so can't give you my skype id as in office i cant add a person outside the office.

Comment: ok i understand........  please come on gmail my id is ranjeetsinghsajwan@gmail.com...

Comment: Sorry dude but chat is disabled in office cant help in that case

Comment: U can post your queries here i will be glad to respond.

Comment: Hey Ranjeet download the pdf from the following link and it will solve all your doubts and queires.                                         http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=12&ved=0CB0QFjABOAo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunesconnect.apple.com%2Fdocs%2FiTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf&ei=1oDvTMK0FIqovQOvsrCaDg&usg=AFQjCNHIe5z2hgZca_u0YEjm4U3sU_3b-g&sig2=9BK8FS_s05iGgIVboVhHXQ